# Inserting values in one array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with ng-repeat and [$index]. My problem is that I would like values from all inputes (look on fiddle and click "+") store in one array and next save in database. The problem is at the very beginning that I can't insert inputs values in one array (first array isn't insert into array). I try use:

```
ng-repeat="input in inputs track by $index"
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j6uwhb6v/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the first input is outside of the ng-repeat so it doesn't have an $index... Here's a simple fix:

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="productController" ng-controller="productCtrl" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input ng-disabled="product.disabled" type="text" ng-model="description[0]" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description..." required>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <a ng-click="addfield()" class="add-field">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </a>                           
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="item in inputs track by $index">
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 repeat-input">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input ng-disabled="product.disabled" type="text" name="description" ng-model="description[$index+1]" class="form-control" placeholder="Description..." required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{description}}
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.inputs = [];
$scope.addfield = function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({})
}  
$scope.description = [];
```

Working Code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svbekepa/1/)